# Alternative of FarmWarDeployer

Tags: tomcat

Hi since FarmWarDeployer is broken in Tomcat6. So is there any alternative to deploy the application in the tomcat cluster without deploying in each and every node.

 
Is this compatible with tomcat7?
Thanks

Comment: Yes of course FarmWarDeployer is compatible with the Tomcat7. Sorry for the late updation